# Neo4j Cypher: Handling whitespace and wildcards in a Lucene fulltext search

Tags: lucene, neo4j, cypher

I created a FullText index named: `myFullTextIndex`.

When I want to search for the pattern:  `Hello World`, the query looks like:

```
START w=node:myFullTextIndex('title:"Hello World"')
```

That works pretty well.

However, I don't manage to search for the same string surrounded by wildcards.
I expect a search on this pattern to return a result: `*Hello World*`

I tried:

```
START w=node:myFullTextIndex('title:"*Hello World*"')
```

and

```
START w=node:myFullTextIndex('title:*"Hello World"*')
```

but doesn't work (syntax errors occurred).

Any idea?

Comment: I found this post explaining the reason: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/neo4j/tedDZkwwHXc/CX6x93B39A0J

Comment: I found out [in other SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25553998/neo4j-lucene-phrase-matching-using-cypher-fuzzy) that whitespaced phrases need to be surrounded with backticks **if** followed by ~ operator and whole Lucene query surrounded with () brackets. Fuzzy query worked for me. In your wildcards case, try `START w=node:myFullTextIndex('title:(*Hello World*)')` - that worked in the handpicked tests in my database. Please let me know how it goes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using complex operators and whitespaces, surround the embedded Lucene query with () brackets.

In your case with wildcards, the following Cypher works in the handpicked tests in my database.

`START w=node:myFullTextIndex('title:(*Hello World*)')`

where Lucene part is

```
*Hello World*
```

Note that () brackets embed the Lucene subpart safely within the Cypher syntax.

See also [Neo4j: Lucene phrase matching using Cypher (fuzzy)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25553998/neo4j-lucene-phrase-matching-using-cypher-fuzzy)

Comment: brackets work outside Lucene too: `MATCH (n:MyLabel{name:('foo')})  RETURN n` works the same as `MATCH (n:MyLabel{name:'foo'})  RETURN n`