# Full text search in Neo4j with spaces

Tags: lucene, neo4j, full-text-search, cypher

When the neo4j lucene auto index is in exact mode (which is the default) queries of the type:

```
start n=node:node_auto_index('name:asfd\\ a*') return n
```

Work correctly (assuming you have a node with the name `asdf adsf` for instance.

However when switching the index to "fulltext" mode following [these instructions](http://jexp.de/blog/2014/03/full-text-indexing-fts-in-neo4j-2-0/) (including deleting the index and reassigning the indexed property), then the same query doesn't return any results.

## Original Question

Trying to search neo4j via the full text index when putting the wildcard character after a space doesn't work.

See the Graph Gist : http://gist.neo4j.org/?74c5a0bb4587cf4b5489

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Embed Lucene part of Cypher with another pair of () brackets.

[Lucene query syntax documentation](http://lucene.apache.org/core/2_9_4/queryparsersyntax.html) states that:

> Lucene supports single and multiple character wildcard searches within single terms (not within phrase queries).

Therefore you can't use `*` wildcard with phrase (this will not work: `"asfd a*"`). Instead, search for two single terms with `AND` operator:

`start n=node:node_auto_index('name:(asfd AND a*)') return n`

Comment: See also [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25553998/neo4j-lucene-phrase-matching-using-cypher-fuzzy) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21615300/neo4j-handling-white-space-in-a-fulltext-search-with-cypher)

Answer (score 3):

To use a space in a index query on a legacy index use two backslashes, since one gets *eaten* by cypher:

```
 start n=node:node_auto_index('name:asfd\\ a*') return n
```

If Cypher is used from Java you need four backslashes due to java string quoting.

Comment: Thanks Stefan, but I've tried that as the last query in the Gist Doublequotes and double escaped space doesn’t work - (No error but NO RESULTS)

Comment: my latest change on my fork makes it work: https://gist.github.com/sarmbruster/6c4ff65b4519386e0d9d/revisions you basically need to remove the double quotes around the search term.

Comment: Thanks again Stefan, indeed the graph gist works and it helps me further isolate my problem! I've edited the question since I'm encountering a problem when using a fulltext index instead of an exact index.

Answer (score 0):

You could write your query as:

```
MATCH (n)
WHERE n.name =~ 'asfd.*'
RETURN n
```

More information is here: http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/query-where.html

Comment: Will that use the lucene full text engine?

Comment: no, this will not use indexes. It's a query look up every node and filter upon property.

Comment: For the use of full text indexes with Neo4j up to 2.2 see: http://jexp.de/blog/2014/03/full-text-indexing-fts-in-neo4j-2-0/