# How to implement Full text search in neo4j?

Tags: jdbc, neo4j, lucene

Currently, we are building our neo4j project using neo4j-jdbc drivers. We are performing all the operations like creating nodes with properties, deleting nodes and creating relations between two nodes using cypher queries.
The sample code is like this

```
Class.forName("org.neo4j.jdbc.Driver");

// Connect
 Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:neo4j://localhost:7474/");

// Querying
try(Statement stmt = con.createStatement())
{
  ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("MATCH (n:User) RETURN n.name");
  while(rs.next())
  {
    System.out.println(rs.getString("n.name"));
  }
}
```

We are performing all the basic searching using cypher queries clauses.
I have studied about the indexing in neo4j tried to understand that too but still not succeeded in understanding whats full-text indexing exactly means.

Now we have to apply full text searching in our project but we are not getting any idea of how to use *Lucene Queries* with Cypher Queries to apply for full-text search.  The sample code we got of use of Lucene query in neo4j was by using an embedded database or rest API.

**PROBLEM:-**

1. Full-text search in neo4j.
2. Embed lucene queries in cypher queries.
3. Full-text Indexing.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25450308/full-text-search-in-neo4j-with-spaces this hould help you.

Comment: I have read this question.Its not helpful to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are some [basic string comparison operators](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-operators.html#query-operators-comparison) available in Cypher, including `STARTS WITH`, `ENDS WITH`, and `CONTAINS`.

For example:

```
MATCH (n.User) WHERE n.name STARTS WITH "Bob" RETURN n;
```

For more powerful full text indexing you will need to use what Neo4j refers to as [Legacy Indexes](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/indexing.html). See [this blog post](http://jexp.de/blog/2014/03/full-text-indexing-fts-in-neo4j-2-0/) for an overview.

Once you have enabled the legacy auto index you can reference it in a `START` clause in Cypher passing any lucene query. For example:

```
START user=node:node_auto_index("name:Bob*")
...
```

Comment: **legacy** auto index sounds like something deprecated right?

Comment: To help clear up the naming confusion legacy indexes are now called explicit indexes and the most recent version of Neo4j has added some procedures for working with them: see http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/schema/index/#explicit-indexes-procedures