# Neo4j: Lucene phrase matching using Cypher (fuzzy)

Tags: lucene, neo4j, cypher

[In Lucene, a Phrase](http://lucene.apache.org/core/3_6_2/queryparsersyntax.html) is a group of words surrounded by double quotes such as "hello dolly".
I would like to be able to do the CYPHER equivalent of this Lucene fuzzy query:

`"hello dolly"~0.1`

This finds my `"hello dolly"` node:

`START n=node:node_auto_index("name:\"hello dolly\"~0.1") RETURN n`

This doesn't:

`START n=node:node_auto_index("name:\"hella dolly\"~0.1") RETURN n`

Splitting the search phrase by whitespace into Single Terms does work:

`START n=node:node_auto_index("name:hella~0.1 AND name:dolly~0.1") return n`

However, my data might contain string like `"HelloDolly"` which I would like to have matched successfully with my `"hello dolly"` node.

### EDIT:

Some other attempts:

`START n=node:node_auto_index("name:hello\\ dolly") RETURN n`
   ----> does work (finds my "hello dolly" node, but is not fuzzy

`START n=node:node_auto_index("name:hello\\ dolly~0.00001") RETURN n`
----> doesn't work (finds nothing)

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
START n=node:node_auto_index("name:hella\\ dolly~0.1") RETURN n
```

Comment: didn't find the "hello dolly" node. I've added some more tests into the question edit.

Answer (score 1):

It's an old question but this may help others:

```
START n=node:node_auto_index('name:"hella dolly"~0.1') RETURN n
```